# Prevent selection change with mouse in a TextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox, selection

In WPF, is there a way to prevent text selection change as a result of user's mouse activity? I have tried setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`, but seems to take away a few other functionalities as well.

I'm basically creating a "masked textbox", that shows TIME in "HH:MM AM" format and allows user to press Up/Down keys to change the values of Hour, Minute and AM/PM parts. Left and Right arrow keys let user move between the parts. The active part is shown through text selection, so I don't want user to be able to click somewhere to change the selection.

Comment: you want user not to change text in your textbox?

Comment: @nit: Not through typing at least. Read my edit above.

Comment: you can set your TextBox.IsReadOnly = true.. in that way user can not type inside your textbox

Comment: Read my explanation plz. My textbox is already readonly, but that doesn't stop user from changing text selection in it through mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to handle PreviewMouseDown or PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event depending from requirements:

```
<TextBox Text="some text" PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

and in the handler:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```